# CSS object not taking up 100% of width

Tags: html, css

After about 9 years, I'm getting back into web programming.  So much has changed!

I've made some progress on my site, but one thing is really irking me.  I followed a tutorial for a static header at the top of the screen.
http://www.cssreset.com/creating-fixed-headers-with-css/

Easy enough, but the line I've got going across the screen (by setting bottom-border in the header class) doesn't go all the way to the left.  Looks like it has a few pixels to go.  The right side seems okay, by comparison.

Pretty straight forward, and easy

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

You can see the page in action here:
http://onfilm.us/image_index.html

Comment: Welcome back to StackOverflow! Instead of adding `[SOLVED]` in the title (which is good on forums and other non-SO places), you can instead accept the answer that solved it, by clicking on the checkmark below the voting buttons.

Comment: Done.  I actually knew that but it slipped my mind. :-/

Comment: @kiss-o-matic: I guess you accepted the answer but forgot to remove the [SOLVED] from the title mate. It is not really required, so I have rolled it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `body` margin to zero. By default browsers have a non-zero value for it, and that's what is causing it.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

You may want to look into using a `reset.css` to zero out margins and paddings and so on so you avoid these issues. Here's a site that links to a bunch of them: http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: Thanks - that was it!  Also thanks for the reset tip. Will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

In your onfilm.css file, add `margin: 0;` in your body tag

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

It should fix your problem! A good practice is to use a reset.css file as describe here : http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

Comment: Thanks! Love 1-line solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Is the header contained inside another html element? Maybe the parent of your header is not 100% and it has a left margin, so when you give the header a 100% width it takes the width of its parent.